# Does every pseudometric give rise to a topology?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I have this example in mind:

> Let $S= \{a,b,c\}$ and define $d:S \times S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $d(x,y) = 0$ for all $x,y \in S$.

This is a pseudometric because it is symmetric, non-negative and $x = y \implies d(x,y) = 0$, and the triangle inequality holds. For the open sets we have only the whole set, how can we get the empty set from the open balls here?

Comment: The same way you get the empty set in the space $X=\{a\}$ with the (non-pseudo) **metric** $d(a,a)=0$?

Comment: The open balls form a **base** for the topology, but every open set doesn't have to be an **intersection** of basic open sets, you can take **unions** too. What is the union of an **empty** collection of open balls?

Comment: If one is alowed to take the **union** of of an **empty** collection, then the empty set is that union. But can one take that union ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In any pseudometric space $(X,d)$ we define a natural topology

$$\mathcal{T}_d:= \{O \subseteq X\mid \forall x \in O: \exists r>0: B(x,r) \subseteq O\} \text{, where } B(x,r)=\{y \in X: d(x,y) < r\}$$

This can easily be verified to be a topology. $\emptyset$ is always open as we quantify universally over an empty domain and for $O=X$ we can always take $r=1$ for any $x$, e.g. In your example: $B(x,r)=X$ for any $x\in X, r>0$ so $$\forall O \in \mathcal{T}_d: O \neq \emptyset \implies O =X, \text{ so } \mathcal{T}_d = \{\emptyset, X\}$$

i.e. we get the trivial (indiscrete) topology on $X$ for the trivial $0$-pseudometric.

Answer (score 2):

The open balls form a [base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)) of the topology. The empty set is obtained as the union of the empty family.

Answer (score 1):

This pseudometric give rise to the indiscrete or [trivial topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_topology). Since $d(x,y)=0$ for all $x,y$, there is one non-empty open ball which is the space $S$ itself. And of course there is the empty ball obtained with a union of an empty family. You can read in the link that in fact every indiscrete space is a pseudometric space with the trivial distance that you have defined, and the converse is also true.

Comment: I think we are not allowed to takes the radius to be zero, open balls are always with positive radius

Comment: That is a convention, but in this case taking the radius to be 0 gives you the whole space, so it was wrong.